# FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED with ROWNUM on ORACLE 12c

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle

I searched all the forum but I didn't find any clue about it. 
I have a staging table that multiple threads consume. 
To avoid deadlock, I'm using something like this:

```
SELECT ID_MESSAGE
FROM TB_STAGE_IN S 
WHERE S.CD_STATUS = 0 
AND S.ID_JOB_SCHEDULE IS NULL 
AND ROWNUM <= 10000 
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

It works fine, but the threads don't reach the max of 10,000 rows. 
It's like:

- Thread 1: 5000
- Thread 2: 3000
- Thread 2: 2000

I know that happens because the rownumber for them is the same, but the table has thousands and thousands of rows. What I really need is the thread gets 10,000 rows unlocked on every step.

I tried using FETCH FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY, but I receive the message below: 
ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.

Could you all please help me?

Thanks for the kind.

Comment: `SKIP LOCKED` happens _after_ the `WHERE` clause.  So your query finds 10,000 rows and then returns the subset of those 10,000 that aren't locked.

Comment: That's why the three threads can't get 10k rows each. What I want is to get 10k on every thread. The table itselfs holds more than a million rows.

Comment: `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` will chunk up your table and execute multiple workers to process the chunks.  It sounds like you are trying to re-invent that.  If you insist on rolling your own design here, there is no magic Oracle way to do what you want.  Instead, you will need each worker to write and commit (possibly in autonomous txn) the rows that it has grabbed for processing.  That way, each worker can grab rows that aren't already assigned.  Since you are committing data, you will need to make sure workers cannot fail without deleting those "lock" indicators.

Comment: I will learn this, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is it important that a job grabs exactly 10000 rows each time? If you have polling jobs they grab a slack handful of tasks, progress them, than back to grab another slack handful. Is the problem that you have a fixed overhead for the step, and you need to minimise the number of times it's executed?

Comment: That's exactly what I need it APC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask Tom has a [suggestion](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=select-for-update-skip-locked) that goes like this

```
open C;  -- cursor C is select ... for update skip locked;

loop
  fetch C bulk collect into :my_array limit 100;
  append :my_array to :to_be_processed_array;
  exit when c%notfound or :to_be_processed_array.count >= 10000;
end loop;

-- process any rows in :to_be_processed_array

close C;
```

Comment: Yes! I used this approach after a little conversation on Ask Tom forums.